# Trying to update Django model with dynamic variable

Tags: python, django

I am trying to update a Django model with dynamic data, like so:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(pk=id).update(key=None)
```

`key` here is a string variable, based on the key from some array.

However when I try to run this, I get this:

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldDoesNotExist: MyModel has no field named 'key'
```

Which makes sense, it is looking for a field key.

How do I tell it I want to use the actual value of the string variable for the key, rather than `key`?

Comment: Can you please share your `MyModel`. What database do you use? What is `key`?

Comment: MySQL. key is a variable, and it iterates over each of the database fields. For example, I have the fields "b", "f", and "p", and I want key to hold all of those values (and about 30 more as it iterates). I have a table that won't change very much, and I am writing a one-off script to check if a field in the table has a corresponding value in another table.

Comment: I literally just want key, the string variable, to be viewed as a key by Django, not the word "key". That's it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass dict of keyword arguments to the function calling like so

```
some_dict = {
    'some_field': 'some value',
}

MyModel.objects.filter(pk=id).update(**some_dict)
```